# Determine if a set is open

Tags: general-topology

> > How can one determine whether the set $$A = \{(x,y)\mid 4\sqrt{3}y-13x^2-7y^2-6\sqrt{3} xy-4x \geq 0\}$$ is open

How can this be done, and what is the actual meaning of a set being open? How can this be illustrated?

Comment: It's obviously closed, so ($\Bbb R^2$ being connected) it could only be open if it's either empty or the whole plane. It's certainly not the whole plane, but is it empty?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown - How do you see that it's obviously closed?

Comment: The meaning of a set being open, intuitively, is that it doesn't contain its boundary. And @LordSharktheUnknown, I would think it more obvious that it is not empty than that it is not the whole plane: it clearly contains the origin.

Comment: In the *usual* topology?

Answer (score 1):

The only subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ that are both open and closed are $\mathbb R^2$ itself and $\varnothing.$

The set $\{(x,y)\mid 4\sqrt{3}y-13x^2-7y^2-6\sqrt{3} xy-4x \geq 0\}$ is the inverse-image of the closed set $[0,\infty)$ under the continuous function $(x,y)\mapsto 4\sqrt{3}y-13x^2-7y^2-6\sqrt{3} xy-4x \geq 0.$

That function is continuous because it is a polynomial function.

The inverse-image of a closed set under a continuous function is closed. Therefore the set in question is closed. Therefore it is open only if it is either $\mathbb R^2$ or $\varnothing.$ It is not all of $\mathbb R^2$ since it fails to contain the point $(1,0).$ It is not empty, since, as "Arthur" pointed out, it contains the origin. So it is not open.

Comment: Michael.Correct me if wrong: Given A={(x,y)| g(x,y) \ge 0}, g continuous, you can say immediately : A as the inverse image of a cont. g of [0,\infty) , a closed set, is closed. Remains to determine if, in addition to being closed, it is open, and this is the case for 1) A=R^2 or 2) A= empyt set. If you have 1) or 2) you would then say: A is open AND closed.Thanks, Peter

Comment: we need the inverse function to be continuous here right? not just the original function that mapped (x,y) -> R

Comment: @H_1317 : No. The inverse image of a closed set under a continuous function is closed regardless of whether the inverse function is continuous.

Comment: and just to be clear: if the polynomial does not map to all of B = [0,infinity), do we not care that B would then contain more points in the range than the original set A would? Since any points not in the range would have the empty set as a inverse image and the empty set union with a set acts as an identity operator?

Comment: @H_1317 : I'm not sure why you want to be concerned about that. The empty set is a closed set.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be clear this wasn't really meant to be an answer but only to help you get some intuition and it was a little too long to be a comment

It's closed because it contains the limit points of the set.  Roughly here's the idea:  Suppose you have a sequence of points $(x_n,y_n) \in B:=  \{(x,y)\mid 4\sqrt{3}y-13x^2-7y^2-6\sqrt{3} xy-4x > 0\}\subset A$  (yes I intended to have $>$ and not $\ge$).  Then the limit of $(x_n,y_n)$ may not lie in $B$ but it will lie in $A$..... so $A$ $A$ contains its limit points and is therefore closed.  Almost always when you see $>$ or $<$ think "open" and when you see $\ge$ or $\le$ think "closed".  Of course, you need to actually prove that $A$ contains its limit points.

Comment: the other answer is the technically correct way to think of this problem, I hope my comment adds some intuition.